# Python Tkinter Stippling an arc

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a chess game in Tkinter using python. For shading on the pieces, I intend to use stippling, however, although the stipple pattern appears on one of the shapes, it does not work on the arc. Here is the relevant code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
win = Canvas(master, width=800, height=800)

def draw(x, y):    #draws a pawn
    win.create_oval(x-15, y-40, x+15, y-10, fill="#FFFFFF")    #head
    win.create_arc(x-15, y-40, x+15, y-10, style=CHORD, start=225, extent=135, stipple="gray25")    #head shading (not appearing stippled)
    win.create_polygon(x+8, y-12, x-8, y-12, x-15, y-5, x-10, y-5, x-20, y+30, x-30, y+35, x-30, y+40, x+30, y+40, x+30, y+35, x+20, y+30, x+10, y-5, x+15, y-5, fill="#FFFFFF", outline="black")    #body
    win.create_polygon(x-10, y-5, x+10, y-5, x+15, y+15, stipple="gray25")    #body shading (appearing stippled)
    win.pack()
    master.update()

draw(400, 400)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is something not directly possible in most Tkinter versions, at least on a Windows platform.

From: http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/tkinter/x3009-options.htm

under "Oval options":

> "As of Tk 8.0, the stipple option is ignored on the Windows platform.
>   To draw stippled ovals, you have to create corresponding polygons."

If this isn't your situation, there's also a note in the documentation stating that you need to specify a fill in order to stipple an oval/arc/chord

In any case, a polygon that approximates the chord would work . . . though it seems like a pain to have to do it that way.