# how to create a semi-transparent oval in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Was trying to create a transparent oval in Tkinter with the `stripple` option but it doesn't seem to work.

```
canvas= Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.create_oval(10,50,70,110, tags="tile", fill="blue", stipple="gray50", activestipple="gray50")
```

I also tried `activestipple="gray50"` but doesn't seem to do anything either.
It works fine on rectangles:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(10,50,40,90, tags="tile", fill="#9a0eea", stipple="gray12")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wouldn't `fill=""` work?

Comment: sorry, I meant semi-transparent, I do want the circle to be colored, but I want to be able to see what is drawn below it

Comment: There is a problem with Oval and Arc, stipple doesn't work. here is a link that may help explain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964416/python-tkinter-stippling-an-arc    You could use Polygons instead.